# Architecting a PHP application from procedural to Object Oriented

Tags: php, oop, frameworks, content-management-system, procedural-programming

I am working on a CMS application which has been written in procedural style of php programming.But now as the new features are to be added,it becomes difficult to handle some parts as the application.It is reaching to a complex stage and **we need to RESPECT the complexity**.
So,now we are planning to build it using the object oriented style of programming which is a better approach in terms of control.But,its difficult to make out where to start from?
What I mean is,which parts would be converted to classes,what exactly would be the model part and also I want to be able manage a centralised control over the application control as it a CMS ,it will have domain and sub-domain creation.
One thing I am clear is a database class will be needed with select,update,insert,delete functions and connection details,but other modules like **login/registration,payment process,Email functionality using templates,logging and debugging,Exceptions handling**(Messages for success and failure). Will converting them to classes make a difference?
Is there any **framework or CMS**,(Tried referring wordpress/codeignitor,but I can adopt only few features out of it) I can refer which does something like this?
I know it is a bit descriptive but I am new to Object oriented php programming and I have never architected any application.**This is a learning process and I would like the expert suggestions/views as I have been getting earlier to make a decision**.
Thank you  for your time

Comment: Try `Symfony2`, it isn't easy to learn, but at the end when you refactor all your code into bundles, it'll be much easier to maintain.

Comment: @TomaszKowalczyk I would like something easy as the learning curve would hamper the time.I can understand it will help over a time,but what we are trying is to build something customized to our requirements,maybe writing our own classes but by using some reference as frameworks bcoz there is no point in reinventing what has been already done.Right?

Comment: *"Use a framework"* does not even remotely answer the question.

Comment: @rdlowrey you can always lay out UML for class structure for an application you do not know. And why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: @E_p The popular frameworks are a substandard example of OOP. And they're an *awful* example of MVC. A UML class structure has nothing to do with a framework. You shouldn't reinvent the wheel, but you should also not use third-party code you don't understand. Also, frameworks are something of an infestation in PHP-land. I'd consider reading ircmaxell's article, [Framework Fixation - An Anti Pattern](http://blog.ircmaxell.com/2012/07/framework-fixation-anti-pattern.html), because he's more eloquent than I can be in this comment space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pick any of major PHP frameworks ZendFramework, Symfony, Silex, Slim ... and build your CMS on those. Those framework already have most of components you need. Plus they have big communities behind, so you will not have to maintain that code.

If you still want to write your own framework. Take a look in to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller for Handling requests.
No need to create DB classes as PDO http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php is a nice built in abstraction layer you can use.

Comment: Thanks.I am not sure what would be the learning curve for each one.If possible I will go through all,but I want to keep things simple and try out something which is very close to what I am in search of.

Comment: Telling someone who doesn't know the first thing about OO design to use a framework is what I would consider "very poor advice."

Comment: Better let them destroy a project in production.

Comment: Better not to allow people who don't know what they're doing write mission-critical software.

Comment: Updated my post with more generic answer

Comment: @rdlowrey and E_p I have a good understanding of OOP concepts as I have some Java background,but its something new for me in PHP.Also,the timeline does not allow me to spend much time on learning something which I am not sure about using.So I am in a dilemma how to tackle the issue.Thank you for the inputs. :P

Comment: @E_p Will go through it and work out accordingly.Thank you for the views